# Variation of coupon collector's problem: types of coupon are divided into sets, find expected number of coupons for first complete set

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, coupon-collector-problem

Suppose you are collecting coupons from a pool of 50 distinct types. These types can be divided into 10 sets of 5 types each. What is the expected number of coupons you need to collect in order to obtain your first complete set of 5 types?